# S3CopyObjectOperator - An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the CopyObject operation: The specified key does not exist

Tags: airflow

If I run this locally in the cli it runs successfully and copies the files from another  bucket/key to mine into the correct location.

```
aws s3 sync s3://client_export/ref/commissions/snapshot_date=2022-01-01/  s3://bi-dev/KSM/refinery29/commissions/snapshot_date=2022-01-01/
```

When I try with the S3CopyObjectOperator I see the NoSuchKey error:

```
copy_commissions_data = S3CopyObjectOperator(
    task_id='copy_commissions_data',
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    source_bucket_name='client_export',
    dest_bucket_name='bi-dev',
    source_bucket_key='ref/commissions/snapshot_date=2022-01-01,
    dest_bucket_key='KSM/refix/commissions/snapshot_date=2022-01-01',
    dag=dag
)
```

I've also tried adding a `/` before and after the key names and both but I get the same error

Comment: i get the same error, but i think its because you cant do recursive copies of folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quote in the end of line 6, should be:
source_bucket_key='ref/commissions/snapshot_date=2022-01-01',